# Logic formulation question (Primes and twin primes)

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

What follows is entirely speculative and almost certainly impossible, but I wanted to see if the *logic* works or not.

*Theorem* [Euclid]: The set of prime numbers is infinite.

*Conjecture* [Wildly Unlikely Without Hallucinogens]: An algorithm or function exists that takes a prime number $p_i$ as its input, and has as its output $(p_j, p_{j+1})$, where $p_{j+1} = p_j + 2$ and $p_j > p_i$.

For any prime, this algorithm can produce a larger pair of twin primes. Since there are an infinite number of primes, such an algorithm would imply an infinite number of twin primes.

*Conclusion* [Assuming a Ridiculous Premise]: The TPC is true.

Does the *logic* here hold? That is, does the conclusion follow from the premises, even if one of the premises is ridiculous? Or does the logic also make no sense? (I don't think this counts as a proof by induction, right?)

I suppose one could also ask "Is the crazy conjecture above equivalent to the TPC?"

---

The question of *why* such an algorithm is hard or impossible to find is another ball of wax of course.

Comment: The logic is perfectly valid. Actually, in Number Theory there are a lot of "conditional" results. For example, theorems of the form "If the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then we have ...."

Comment: Also, I don't see why to despise the conjecture, calling it "Wildly Unlikely Without Hallucinogens" and "Ridiculous". It could happen that someone find such algorithm, thus proving the TPC.

Comment: That said. That's not how important conjectures are done. For a conjecture to be interesting and worth of study, usually it must be based on some kind of evidence,  heuristics or intuition from people who know well the field.

Comment: Of course, *if* the twin primes conjecture is true, then there definitely is such an algorithm: given $p_i$, just scan the integers in ascending order starting at $p_i$ until the next twin prime pair is found.

Comment: @GregMartin Well, that's certainly *an* algorithm!

Comment: @jjagmath Right, I didn't mean this was a formal conjecture of any sort. More just looking to be certain my logic wasn't completely wrong. Maybe *I'll* find the algorithm! (But I wouldn't bet on it.)  And yeah, the number of results that start with "If we assume RH" is astounding.

Comment: A constructive proof of the twin prime conjecture is even more unlikely than a proof of the twin prime conjecture itself. How difficult they are to to find can be demonstrated by the last known twin prime. Of this pair, both primes have "just" about $300\ 000$ digits compared to over $24$ million digits , which is the magnitude of the largest known prime.

Comment: In other words, a useful algorithm which allows to determine extremely large twin primes in a reasonable time, does almost surely not exist. But since the twin prime conjecture is almost surely true (we have strong evidence, just not a proof yet), in principle there is (almost surely) an algorithm, it is just useless in practice to find extremely large pairs.

Comment: The conclusion "infinite many primes->infinite many twin primes" however is utterly wrong.  The existence of infinite many primes alone does not imply that infinite many twin primes must exist. There are , for example only finite many idoneal numbers. This is a nontrivial result. There is no obvious reason for this finiteness. So, although infinite many positive integers exist, we have not infinite many idoneal numbers.